# Peeling exterior paint

Tags: paint

I had a new roof built with all new facia board and painted. My issue is just about every year the paint peels down to the wood on all of the facia board. I scrape and clean and paint and it still happens. The facia board is a hangover from the house and not against the home itself. The roof is new with new drip ends . What do I do???

Comment: Are you using a primer before painting?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add a picture of the problem? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I am using a primer/paint

Comment: What type of board / product is the facia made out of?

Answer (score 1):

Moisture gets in the wood and then the heat (and sun) will bring the moisture out to the surface. This causes the paint to blister and peel.

Exterior wood (especially fascia hung away from a building) should be primed on all sides to keep the moisture out.

You may need to protect the wood boards with a tarp until they are “dry”.  Pic a day when it’s not too humid.

Often paint will peel if there is no interior moisture barrier. However, this is not your problem, because the boards are away from the house.

You may need to check to see that rain is not seeping down between the roof and the fascia board. This could soak the wood and make the paint blister when the sun comes out. That’s why all edges need to be primed when dry.